# Can I license my project under GPL when I use Apache-licensed libraries?

Tags: android, licensing

First off, I know that I officially have to ask questions concerning licenses on the Open Source community but I've seen enough questions about it here and posts there get as much views in a day as you'd get here in about 3 minutes.

That said, I have done quite some research already and I think I know the answer to my question but I want to be sure I get this right. I've spent too much time on my project over the last few years to screw it all up with a wrong license.

I'm currently working on an Android application which I want to release as open source at a later moment. I want everyone to be able to contribute to the project but I also want forks of the project to be open source. That's why I initially chose GPLv2 as my license, but I've been reading that it's very restrictive in its 'openness'. At the moment I'm only using Apache v2.0-licensed libraries in my project and as far as I was able to find, the Apache v2.0 license is compatible with GPLv2.

**TL;DR**
Am I allowed to license and distribute my Android project under GPLv2 when it consists of Apache v2.0-licensed libraries and the code I've written myself? Or is there a better alternative for my wishes?

Comment: Thank you so much @Thilo, I must have completely missed that document :) Would you mind posting your answer as an actual answer so I can mark the question as answered??

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it concerns software licensing, rather than programming.

Comment: Like I said in the first paragraph, I know it's in the wrong place but I just wanted an answer fast

Comment: Thanks for clarifying that, I didn't know the rules on what can be asked were that strict but I totally get your point that it sets a bad example. Though I hope that my first paragraph will point others in the right direction. And on a sidenote, Thilo answered my question by linking to a document writen by the Apache guys, so I deemed that a valid answer

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about licensing instead of directly about programming. [[See here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/274963/1402846)] for details and the [[help]] for more.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Apache Foundation has [a document about GPL compatibility](http://www.apache.org/licenses/GPL-compatibility.html).

Choice quotes:

> Apache 2 software can therefore be included in GPLv3 projects, because the GPLv3 license accepts our software into GPLv3 works. However, GPLv3 software cannot be included in Apache projects.
>
> Despite our best efforts, the FSF has never considered the Apache License to be compatible with GPL version 2

So it seems you should be fine with including Apache code in GPLv3 projects (not such much with GPLv2).

For the practical aspects of how to include non-GPL code into GPL projects also see this [advice from the Software Freedom Law Center](http://www.softwarefreedom.org/resources/2007/gpl-non-gpl-collaboration.html).